# How to find the number of threads waiting for mutex lock in Sync.Mutex?

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, mutex

I am using this in a go subroutine

```
    a.Lock()
    ...
    enter code here
    ...
    a.Unlock()
```

Is there any api to know how many threads are waiting at a.Lock()?

Comment: You might want to present the original problem you're trying to solve because I sense a possibility for [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) here: if you are merely interested in "sampling the level of contention" on the resource(s) protected by that mutex, that'd be one thing (you cannot do that with a mutex), but if you'd like to have something like [counting semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)), that'd be completely another problem with a number of possible solutions.

Comment: (Well, actually estimating the level of contention is also possible—say, make each client increment an atomic integer (see `sync/atomic`) before taking a lock and decrement it after releasing it: at any time you can read that integer and know the number of waiting goroutines. In your example, when that variable would be read in the "enter code here" point, if would always be ≥ 1.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any api to know how many threads are waiting at a.Lock()?

No.

(And basically if you need to know that you should redesign your aglorithm.)